Receiving and using cookies in typescript/javascript/html
So im trying to use token for account autentication, so i receive the token from the backend using cookie-parser  like this:
const token = await ViewToken(AccEmail, AccPassword);
res.statusCode = 200;
res.cookie("authToken", token, {httpOnly: false,}).send();

And i receive it succefully in my Login page and after it confirms the login, it redirects the user to another html page, but when i try to use the token cookie from the first page, i isnt there, How do i use cookies received in one html page in another separate html page?
im using this to fetch the cookie:
const resToken = await fetch("http://100.93.233.91:3000/GetToken", {
method: "GET",
headers: h,
credentials: "include",
});
if(resLogin.ok && resToken.ok){
const token = await resToken.json();
localStorage.setItem("authtoken", token);
console.log(localStorage.getItem("authtoken"));
window.location.href = "MainPage.html";
}

but when i console.log(localStorage.getItem("authtoken")); it apears as void
